# SQlite LEFT JOIN returning NULL values when it should not

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have multiple tables. When using LEFT JOIN between tables **part** and **brand** I get the expected result, when I use the same query but between **part** and **partgroup**, all the partgroup data field return *NULL*.

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE part (
    part_ID              PRIMARY KEY,
    reference    TEXT    NOT NULL,
    brand_ID             REFERENCES brand (brand_ID) 
                         NOT NULL,
    partgroup_ID         NOT NULL
                         REFERENCES partgroup (partgroup_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE partgroup (
    partgroup_ID      PRIMARY KEY,
    name         TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE brand (
    brand_ID          PRIMARY KEY,
    name         TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Query that works **part** LEFT JOIN **brand**:

```
SELECT 
    part.part_ID,
    part.brand_ID,
    brand.brand_ID,
    brand.name
FROM 
    part
LEFT JOIN brand ON part.brand_ID = brand.brand_ID;
```

Query that does not work **part** LEFT JOIN **partgroup**:

```
SELECT 
    part.part_ID,
    part.partgroup_ID,
    partgroup.partgroup_ID,
    partgroup.name
FROM 
    part
LEFT JOIN partgroup ON part.partgroup_ID = partgroup.partgroup_ID;
```

[image: Data]

[image: Result of the queries]

Comment: The partgroup_id columns (or their values, since you're using SQLite) in the two tables are 1) the same type, and 2) both numeric, not text? (what I mean is, are you sure that a partgroup_id column in one of the tables is not text and contains `"1 "` (1 with a space after)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This suggests that the keys don't match -- a properly declared foreign key would fix this.  As would a numeric key.

Even though the values look like they are the same, they are not.  Here are some possibilities:

- Leading spaces
- Trailing spaces
- Look-alike characters (say capital O rather than numeric 0)
- Hidden characters

It requires some investigation to figure out what is going on.  You can start by looking at the lengths of the `partId` fields to see if they are the same.

Or, you could just implement a numeric id and use that for foreign key references.  Generally integer keys are more efficient anyway -- because they are of fixed size and smaller than strings.

Comment: the tables got filled using a python script which uses the same value for the partgroup_ID in both tables. I just tried to modify the ID's manually just to be sure there are no hidden characters or spaces but that yielded the same results. I changed data type for all ID's to INTEGER and that does the trick! thanks!